# Can faulty Cooler fans prevent CPU from starting?

Tags: boot, cpu, overheating, heatsink, cpu-cooler

My PC is showing a strange issue. When I start the PC, the power lights glows on, all the fans run. But no Hard disk Activity. And nothing happens. No display, no lights on mouse or keyboard. This happens sometimes and some other times,

- It boots into motherboard logo and stays there.
- Sometimes it says Boot failed insert bootable media - something of this kind.
- Sometimes it stops with those kernel messages and doesn't boot further.
- Sometimes it boots and everything works fine. But freezes randomly(sometimes reboots). I've confirmed it isn't any software bug that causes these freezes.

When I check the CPU temperature, it easily hits 70℃ and more when loading heavy software like Android Studio. Some of my Cooler fan push-pins are broken and the thermal compound looks dried up. I can very well understand this causes overheating. This may be the reason for crashing. But can this prevent the CPU from starting at the 1st place which happens often? Or could there be something else that is faulty also?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can only know how the compound looks by removing the cooler. **NEVER** do that without removing and reapplying the thermal compound. The cost of the cpu vs the cost of a new cooler should rush you to buy a new cooler with no broken push-pins. The not starting issue hint IMO more at a power problem.

Comment: It could also be a failing hard disk. Check your hard drives for SMART errors [How can I read my hard drive's SMART status in Windows 7?](//superuser.com/q/29240), and [What is the easiest method of checking SMART status for your hard drive?](//superuser.com/q/14803). Report back with the results.

Comment: @LotPings: If the fans run then this is not a power problem.

Comment: @harrymc I was referring to the pc not the cooler. I've had problems with an intermittent power good signal from the power supply which led to similar symptoms as OP describes.

Comment: @LotPings But I have removed the cooler fan for cleaning about 20 times now.  I'll get a replacement soon. If it can be power issues, how do I confirm before investing on a PSU?

Comment: @DavidPostill I did remove the hard disk itself from the mother board and try. The CPU still didn't start sometimes(not even BIOS screen was displayed). But anyway I'll try that method.

Comment: Depending on the age of your system I'd always start with the least cost intensive actions.  But you didn't tell much facts and this doesn't seem to be simple to diagnose reason.